# 300 Multiple choices

Tags: html, .htaccess, relative-path

I've got a problem with my website, or more specfically the navigation.

First off the problem;

300 multiple pages; 
It does this to the url

```
   http://mysite.co.uk/services.phpdiamond-plus.php
   http://mysite.co.uk/services.phpdiamond/
```

should be;

```
   http://mysite.co.uk/services/diamond-plus.php
   http://mysite.co.uk/services/diamond.php
```

my file structure;

```
root/services/diamond-plus.php
root/services/diamond.php
```

Doesn't matter what direcory or level I am in when selecting diamond-plus.php, it just brings up this page with the url as it is above, I've got a similar url which happens to the both of them.

I include my navigation and use relative urls like so;

/services/diamond-plus.php

Orignally there was a services.php page in directory above, I've changed that. I didsabled my .htaccess file aswell to test, the problem still persists.

Any ideas?

--- Edit ---

Nav section is included -

```
a href="/services/diamond.php" >Diamond</a
```

.htaccess file

```
options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
Options +Indexes
AcceptPathInfo Off
RewriteEngine on

Redirect 301 /mysite-service-diamondplus.html http://mysite.co.uk/services/diamond-plus.php 

Redirect 301 /mysite-service-diamondplus http://mysite.co.uk/services/diamond-plus.php
```

Having changed nothing, it's not giving me the error anymore.. 
Does changing the .htaccess sometimes take several minutes?

Comment: Can you post some code, please?

Comment: @Vereos Added some minor bits, somehow the error has fixed itself, but I sorta need a permament fix!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+?\.)php([^/]+)$ /$1/$2.php [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.+?\.)php(.+?\.php)$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: How does this code work? is it look to match the file through the directory levels?

Comment: Have you tried these yet in your DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess file? If it doesn't work then let me know for which URLs it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

No RewriteRules are required to fix this..

[image: MultipleChoices300 Error]

If you have index.html or `index.htm` as the first values in `DirectoryIndex` it will try to load those up first.. I put `index.php` as the first script to load up and the Multiple Choices 300 error went away. Although I never even had the Multiple Choices 300 error with my old configuration.. it has something to do with updating PHP to version `v5.4.16` or higher.

Comment: This question was from 2013, so it's likely these measures are now redundant. Thanks for the update.